# In a helm template how can i use items in 1 list to iterate over another list

Tags: kubernetes, helm, go

i want to pre-populate a kubernetes cluster with namespaces and their respective secrets for our apps and services.
For that i would like to be able to specify 2 lists, 1 list with secrets, and 1 list with namespaces. Each namespace in the list has a list of secrets.
Like this values.yaml:

```
secrets:
  - name: secret1
    data: key1
  - name: secret2
    data: key2
  - name: secret3
    data: key3

namespaces:
  - name: app1
    secrets:
      - secret1
      - secret2
  - name: app2
    secrets:
      - secret1
      - secret3
```

Then i want to loop over namespaces to create the namespaces, like:

```
{{- range $namespaces := .Values.namespaces }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: {{ $namespaces.name }}
---
{{- end }}
```

In that loop i want another loop inside this loop that creates the secrets per namespace with the data from the secrets list. A bit like this:

```
{{- range $secrets := .secrets }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ .name }}
  namespace: {{ $namespaces.name }}
type: kubernetes.io/tls
data: $secrets.data
---
{{- end }}
```

But if i put that loop inside the namespace loop, it just creates all secrets in the secrets list in all namespaces. 
How can i make the loop only create the secrets specified in the namespaces list?
I think it can be done with the go template index function, but i don't know how.

Answer (score 13):

I have made reproduction on your problem and find answer for that.

### Your example

I used your yamls to create namespaces and changed the second one so it's actually work now.

**values.yaml**

```
secrets:
  - name: secret1
    data: key1
  - name: secret2
    data: key2
  - name: secret3
    data: key3

namespaces:
  - name: app1
    secrets:
      - secret1
      - secret2
  - name: app2
    secrets:
      - secret1
      - secret3
```

**templates/namespaces.yaml**

```
{{- range $namespaces := .Values.namespaces }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: {{ $namespaces.name }}
---
{{- end }}

{{- range $namespace := .Values.namespaces }}                                                                               
{{- range $secret := $namespace.secrets }}                                                                                  
---                                                                                                                         
apiVersion: v1                                                                                                              
kind: Secret                                                                                                                
metadata:                                                                                                                   
  name: {{ $secret }}                                                                                                       
  namespace: {{ $namespace.name }}                                                                                          
type: kubernetes.io/tls                                                                                                     
data: $secrets.data                                                                                                         
---                                                                                                                         
{{- end }}                                                                                                                  
{{- end }}
```

Result:

```
COMPUTED VALUES:
namespaces:
- name: app1
  secrets:
  - secret1
  - secret2
- name: app2
  secrets:
  - secret1
  - secret3
secrets:
- data: key1
  name: secret1
- data: key2
  name: secret2
- data: key3
  name: secret3

HOOKS:
MANIFEST:

---
# Source: mychart/templates/namespaces.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: app1
---
# Source: mychart/templates/namespaces.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: app2
---
# Source: mychart/templates/namespaces.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secret1
  namespace: app1                  
type: kubernetes.io/tls
data: $secrets.data
---
# Source: mychart/templates/namespaces.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secret2
  namespace: app1                  
type: kubernetes.io/tls
data: $secrets.data
---
# Source: mychart/templates/namespaces.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secret1
  namespace: app2                  
type: kubernetes.io/tls
data: $secrets.data
---
# Source: mychart/templates/namespaces.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secret3
  namespace: app2                  
type: kubernetes.io/tls
data: $secrets.data
```

### My idea of doing that

Instead of creating secrets for namespaces, do it the other way around, create secrets and add namespaces to them.

**values.yaml**

```
Secret1:
- namespace1
- namespace2

Secret2:
- namespace2
```

**templates/namespaces.yaml**

```
{{- range $namespaces := .Values.namespaces }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: {{ $namespaces.name }}
---
{{- end }}
```

**templates/secrets.yaml**

```
{{- range .Values.Secret1 }}
---
apiVersion: v1
data:
  password: MWYyZDFlMmU2N2Rm
  username: YWRtaW4=
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: secret1
  namespace: {{ . }}
{{- end}}
{{- range .Values.Secret2 }}
---
apiVersion: v1
data:
  password: MWYyZDFlMmU2N2Rm
  username: YWRtaW4=
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: secret2
  namespace: {{ . }}
{{- end}}
```

Result:

```
COMPUTED VALUES:
Secret1:
- namespace1
- namespace2
Secret2:
- namespace2
namespaces:
- name: namespace1
- name: namespace2

HOOKS:
MANIFEST:

---
# Source: mychart/templates/namespaces2.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: namespace1
---
# Source: mychart/templates/namespaces2.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: namespace2
---
# Source: mychart/templates/namespaces.yaml
apiVersion: v1                                                                                                              
data:                                                                                                                       
  password: UyFCXCpkJHpEc2I=                                                                                                   
  username: ZGV2dXNlcg==                                                                                                      
kind: Secret                                                                                                                
metadata:                                                                                                                   
  creationTimestamp: null                                                                                                   
  name: secret1                                                                                                             
  namespace: namespace2
---
# Source: mychart/templates/namespaces.yaml
apiVersion: v1                                                                                                              
data:                                                                                                                       
  password: ZGV2dXNlcg==                                                                                              
  username: UyFCXCpkJHpEc2I=                                                                                                    
kind: Secret                                                                                                                
metadata:                                                                                                                   
  creationTimestamp: null                                                                                                   
  name: secret2                                                                                                             
  namespace: namespace2
---
# Source: mychart/templates/namespaces.yaml
apiVersion: v1                                                                                                              
data:                                                                                                                       
  password: UyFCXCpkJHpEc2I=                                                                                                   
  username: ZGV2dXNlcg==                                                                                                      
kind: Secret                                                                                                                
metadata:                                                                                                                   
  creationTimestamp: null                                                                                                   
  name: secret1                                                                                                             
  namespace: namespace1
```

More informations about Flow Control(if,else if,range) can be found [here](https://github.com/technosophos/k8s-helm/blob/master/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures.md#looping-with-the-range-action).

Answer (score 0):

I found this post very usefull.
I need a bit different usecase that i couldn't achieve as of now.

**Values.yaml**

```
    customCerts:
  - name: test
    secrets:
      tls.crt: |
        -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
        xxxx
        -----END CERTIFICATE-----
      tls.key: |
        -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
        xxxx
        -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
  - name: test2
    secrets:
      tls.crt: |
        -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
        xxxx
        -----END CERTIFICATE-----
      tls.key: |
        -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
        xxxx
        -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

**Secret.yaml**

```
{{- range $customCerts := .Values.customCerts }}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ .name }}
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
stringData:
  {{ .secrets  | indent 2 }}
---
{{- end }}
```

I have 2 problems:

- .Release.Namespace doesn't work inside the {{ range }}
- I can't manage to get the secret with {{ .secrets }}

**Edit**:

I fixed the problem with `.Release.Namespace` by adding this at the beginning: `{{- $root := . -}}`  and then use `{{ $root.Release.Namespace }}`

- But i still couldn't fill the secret with the **tls.key** and **tls.crt** entries

**Edit 2:**

i'm now able to list the secrets, but i can't remove the '|' character :

**values.yaml:**

```
customCerts:
  - name: test
    secrets: |
      tls.crt: |
        -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
        xxxx
        -----END CERTIFICATE-----
      tls.key: |
        -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
        xxxx
        -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
  - name: test2
    secrets: |
      tls.crt: |
        -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
        xxxx
        -----END CERTIFICATE-----
      tls.key: |
        -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
        xxxx
        -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

**secrets.yaml:**

```
{{- $root := . -}}
{{- range $customCerts := .Values.customCerts }}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ .name }}
  namespace: {{ $root.Release.Namespace }}
stringData:
  {{ toYaml .secrets }}
---
{{- end }}
```

**Output:**

```
# Source: ciam-app/templates/secretsCustomCerts.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: qbel1-ciam
stringData:
  |
  tls.crt: |
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    xxxx
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
  tls.key: |
    -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    xxxx
    -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
---
# Source: ciam-app/templates/secretsCustomCerts.yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: test2
  namespace: qbel1-ciam
stringData:
  |
  tls.crt: |
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    xxxx
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
  tls.key: |
    -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    xxxx
    -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I can't get rid of the `|` after `stringData`

**Edit 3:**

I finally found a way :

```
  {{ toYaml .secrets | trimPrefix "|" | trim }}
```

Maybe that will help someone else.